# How to make `div` height to fit its content in `flex`?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have below html code and the problem is the height of `.div2` is as same as `body`. How can I make the `div2` height to fit to its content which is the `font size` of `hello`? I know I can make it by changing body display to `block` but I do need `flex` display. Is there a way to make it under `flex` layout?

```css
body {
  width: 923px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
}

.div2 {
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div2">hello</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `align-items:flex-start` on parent element

Comment: that fix my problem. Thank.s